# Printing lines with a character limit per line

Tags: java

I'm reading input from a separate file which contains an entire paragraph. I'm storing the words in the paragraph in a list. My goal is to print out an entire paragraph from a separate file with each line not exceeding a character limit of characters. I'm iterating through the list using:

```
for (String word: words)
```

I'm not sure how to write the code for the character limit. I was thinking of using `StringBuffer` methods, but I'm not sure. Any ideas?

Comment: What is a line to you?  Is each paragraph a line or is there a different mapping?  Is a line whenever you hit a line break/carriage return, etc?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be what you want: [Java's BreakIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/line.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use StringBuffer (or [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) if you don't care about thread safety) to temporarily hold words as you encounter them. To enforce the character limit, you can count the number of characters adding a word would have had before adding it into the buffer. Once you've hit a limit, flush the buffer (into an output buffer/file) and start over.

Here's something quick-and-dirty I just cooked up:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CharLimit {

    static int LIMIT = 79;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(LIMIT);

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(sc.nextLine());
            while (sc2.hasNext()) {
                String nextWord = sc2.next();
                if ((buffer.length() + nextWord.length() + 1) > LIMIT) {
                    // we would have exceeded the line limit; flush
                    buffer.append('\n');
                    System.out.print(buffer.toString());

                    buffer = new StringBuilder(nextWord);
                }
                else {
                    buffer.append((buffer.length() == 0 ? "" : " ") + nextWord);
                }
            }
        }

        if (buffer.length() > 0) {
            System.out.print(buffer.toString() + "\n");
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Example:

```
???:/tmp$ cat input

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

???:/tmp$ java CharLimit < input 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Note that this does not take into account a "word" token that is longer than the pre-configured limit.

Comment: Could you please explain what the .append method does in the StringbBuffer class because I have read the API Documentation for it and I am still unclear. Thanks!

Comment: In the case of `StringBuilder`, `append()` basically adds the character sequence (String) in the function call argument (in our example the current "word"). So, if your buffer currently contains `"Hello,"` then `buffer.append(" World!");` would cause the buffer to now contain `"Hello, World!"`.

Comment: How would I use StringBuffer in this situation? Would it be the same to say StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(LIMIT); ?

Comment: Also, how would the if statement, which is checking for the line limit work. Could you run through an example please?

Comment: Also, could you please explain why there is a +1 in the if condition?

Comment: The if statement checks if adding the current word to the buffer would bring the buffer's total length above the limit. The +1 is to account for adding a space.

Comment: Thank you for the replies! Im beginning to understand how I can solve my problem. However, Im using the for(String word: words) to iterate through a list. And im not sure if I can implement the if condition the same way under this for loop? Pls advise.

Comment: I think that would work just as well. Just try it and post more specific problem you encounter along the way.

Answer (score 0):

My personal implementation. The code is old, from my cowboy days, but it works. Tweak it as you wish.

```
private static final int LINE_LENGTH = 30;
private static final String SPACE = " ";
private static final String EMPTY_STRING = "";

/**
 * Formats the given input text: <br />
 * - Wraps text to lines of maximum <code>LINE_LENGTH</code> <br />
 * - Adds newline characters at each line ending <br />
 * - Returns as a string
 */
public static String getPreviewLines(final String input) 
{
    final StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(input, SPACE);
    final StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(input.length());

    int lineLen = 0;

    while (token.hasMoreTokens()) 
    {
        final String word = token.nextToken() + SPACE;

        if (lineLen + word.length() - 1 > LINE_LENGTH) 
        {
            output.append(System.lineSeparator());
            lineLen = 0;
        }

        output.append(word);

        if (word.contains(System.lineSeparator())) 
            lineLen = word.replaceAll("\\s+", EMPTY_STRING).length(); //$NON-NLS-1$
        else
            lineLen += word.length();
    }

    return output.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    public static int size = 10;
    /**
     * Main Method
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String read = "enter any text here or read it from somewhere else the idea here is to split as many words you want and print it in the format you want";        
    String[] wordArray = read.trim().split(" ");        
    printBySize(size,wordArray);

    }

    private static void printBySize(int size, String[] wordArray) {
        StringBuilder bld = new StringBuilder(size);
        for(int i=0; i<wordArray.length;i++) {

            String word = wordArray[i];

            if ((bld.length() + word.length()) >= size) {
                //if yes add a new line and create a new builder for the new line
                bld.append(lineSeparator);
                System.out.print(bld.toString());
                bld = new StringBuilder(word);
            }
            else {

                bld.append((bld.length() == 0 ? "" : " ") + word);
            }

        }
        System.out.println(bld.toString());
    }
```